# Canvas does not render opaque

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to render basic stuff on a canvas with its GraphicsContext. I set an opaque color for strokes, but the result on screen is slightly transparent.

```
public class Spielwiese extends Application {

   public static void main(String... args) {
      launch(args);
   }

   @Override
   public void start(Stage window) {
      Canvas canvas = new Canvas(800, 600);
      window.setScene(new Scene(new Pane(canvas)));
      window.show();

      GraphicsContext g = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
      g.setFill(Color.BLACK);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
      g.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
      g.strokeRect(16, 16, 64, 64);
   }

}
```

The result:
[image]

I tried setting the transparency of the color myself using `new Color(1, 1, 1, 1)`, but it had the same effect.
However, I managed to get an opaque rectangle by calling the `g.strokeRect(16, 16, 64, 64);` multiple times to stroke over it more than once, but I don't like that "solution".
Is there a way to stroke an opaque shape onto a canvas without stroking over it multiple times?

EDIT: When I copy the statement `g.strokeRect(16, 16, 64, 64);` and put 4 of those at the end of the start method instead of one, I get an opaque rectangle:
[image]

Comment: I understand that the screen capture you posted is the result you don't want. Can you post a screen capture of the result you do want?

Comment: I can't reproduce the effect shown with the code shown.

Comment: Why not? What prevents you from reproducing it?

Comment: I **do** reproduce it on Windows 10 with JavaFX 8.

Comment: @David: I had my display scaled in a way that made the default line width span more than one pixels; at the default scale, I see your result exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `g.setStrokeWidth(2.0);` or similar to your code. If you are drawing very thin lines they appear semi-transparent when they are not exactly aligned with the pixel boundaries.

See for more details: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html

Comment: `g.setLineWidth(2);` before drawing the strokes seems to work.